# Vbscript and HTML Checkboxes, Help?

Tags: html, vbscript

I am a beginner with programming. I have created an HTML page with a text box, text area, select box, checkboxes, and radio buttons. I am trying to show how VBScript works with HTML for a class assignment. One of the tasks is to have a series of editing rules. The one I need help with is  making sure that at least one checkbox is checked before the user can submit the form. How would I do this in VBScript?

Here is my code so far:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript">
<!--
sub fred





end sub
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<form name="f1">
<br>
Name <input type="text" name="nametext" size="30"><p>
List your favorite things to do <P><textarea name="bigtext" rows="5" cols="40">default value</textarea>

<p>What is your favorite animal to see at the zoo?

<select name="zooanimal">
  <option>default value
  <option>elephants
  <option>giraffes
  <option>tigers
  <option>seals
</select>

<p>

What is your favorite color?<br><p>
   blue <input name="rb" type="radio" value="bluechecked" checked> green <input name="rb" type="radio" value="greenchecked">
  pink <input name="rb" type="radio" value="pinkchecked"> yellow <input name="rb" type="radio" value="yellowchecked"> red <input name="rb" type="radio" value="redchecked"> black <input name="rb" type="radio" value="blackchecked"></p>

Which of these games do you play?<br><p>
  Starcraft <input name="game" value="Starcraft" type="checkbox"> World of Warcraft <input name="game" value="WorldofWarcraft" type="checkbox"> 
 League of Legends <input name="game" value="LeagueofLegends" type="checkbox"> none <input name="game" value="none"
 type="checkbox"><P>
 <p><input type="button" value="EDIT AND REPORT" onClick="fred">


<p>

<p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No offense intended Krista, and you didn't ask but..... you should be using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
If (f1.rb.checked = True) Or (f1.game.checked = True) Then
```